# Android layout for timetable

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android developpement and I'm trying to display a timetable in my application.
The problem is I don't know which layouts will suit the best for it. I looked is the layouts but none of them looks to fit correctly.

I would like to display it that way :

```
 __________________________________________ 
|Mon |     | AAA | BBB |  | C | |DD|       | 
|Tu  |   |AA|   |BBBBB|   |DDDD|   |CCCC|  |
| ...
```

That timetable should be horizontaly scrollable so it will be in a HorizontalScrollView I think.

I already though about some layout but I always get the same problem. Each event (AAA,BBB, .... ) can be of a different duration. I though about a tableView with one column for each minute or even 15 minutes  and then playing with layout_span but it seems like there is a bit too much column.
With those layout it seems like there will be another problem about the spaces where there is no event. Maybe it will be solved by creating empty events.

One other constraint, each event will be clickable.

Any ideas about how to implement this is welcome.
(I'm not asking here a complete solution, I need just ideas about how to implement)

Thanks.

Comment: In the meantime, have you found a solution? I'm currently working on my custom view to create everything myself, but I'd love to hear another solution